# ErrorDocument 404 not working with routing

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

I tried using this code on `.htacces` to have my own custom 404 on my page,.

`ErrorDocument 404 http://mysite.com/404.shtml`

when i visit the page that does not exist on the site. it must show something like this

[image]

but this is the one it shows

[image]

here is my complete htaccess

```
<files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</files>
php_value memory_limit 170M

RewriteEngine on


Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteRule (.*) index.php

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]  

ErrorDocument 404 http://mysite.com/404.shtml
```

The location of my `htaccess` is located along with the `404.shtml` and the `index.php` of the site

Removing this code would fix the problem. How can i make it work with routing.

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)$  [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

Comment: missing something after 'it must show something like this'

Comment: are you running under Apache ? you should check if `.htaccess` is enable : [enable htaccess on apache](http://www.tildemark.com/enable-htaccess-on-apache/)

Comment: yap. .htaccess is enabled

Comment: I don't know how other lines are impacting `ErrorDocument` line. But this one looks good. Try to comment other stuffs or rewrite `.htaccess` step by step starting with `ErrorDocument` into.

Comment: removing this code will make it work.
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteRule (.*) index.php`

Comment: is there anyway to fix this without removing the code? its a routing for the site to go to index.php always\

Comment: I commented out #RewriteRule .* index.php [L] in my htaccess file and got ErrorDocument working...#just_sayin

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referencing the entire url with `ErrorDocument 404 http://mysite.com/404.shtml`, name the document relative to your web root. In this case, `/404.shtml`.

Comment: from [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument) both are correct

Answer (score 0):

Use these codes in your .htaccess for capture 404 error pages.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /404.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now your all 404 requests will goto /404.html. You can also use /404.php to code more dynamically. Also make sure that rewrite module is enabled in your apache.